# Como lidar com as caracteres especiais ao introduzir dados ao banco com php+mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Então pessoal, estou tentando inserir alguns dados de uma uma tela de registro no banco, mas quando eu insiro, as caracteres especiais bugam no banco. Segue o código no php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$fullName = $_POST["name"];
$senha = $_POST["password"];
$confirmSenha = $_POST["confirmPassword"];
$rua = $_POST["endereco"];
$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$bairro =  $_POST["bairro"];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "teste");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Failed to connect with MySQL" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}
if ($senha == $confirmSenha) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (fullName,senha,rua,numero,bairro) VALUES('$fullName','$senha','$rua','$numero','$bairro')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo ("<script>alert('Registrado com sucesso!!');</script>");
    } else {
        echo "Erro";
    }
} else {
    echo ("<script>alert('Senhas não são iguais.');window.location.href('telaRegistro.html');</script>");
}
```

E o banco:[image: Banco de dados usado]

No caso, o usuario de id 3 e 5 foi inserido manualmente por uma query no próprio heidisql, os outros que estão bugados forem inseridos por meio do código.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, como vai?

Então, vamos fazer o seguinte, vamos informar qual o [charset](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-set-charset.php) o MySQL deve utilizar para a conexão atual, faremos da seguinte forma:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Após sua conexão, insira o código acima.
Até breve...

Comment: Obrigado, amigo! Resolveu o erro.

Comment: Utilize as ferramentas para [agradecer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas), não há a necessidade de escrever obrigado, porem, por nada!